# How to create and update products to a REST API from Angular

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

I am new to and currently working on a Django and Angular webapp and I cant seem to be able to create and update my products from the angular web app and send them to the REST API to update the server. I have written a delete function and service request that works and I can retrieve the products from the API but I don't know how to write the functions for create products and update products. Would anyone be able to help me here?

Here is what I have so far:

***api.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http'
import { Product } from './models/Product';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Category } from './models/Category';
import { Shop } from './models/Shop';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {


  baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/';
  baseProductUrl = `${this.baseUrl}app/products/`
  baseCategoryUrl = `${this.baseUrl}app/categories/`
  baseShopUrl = `${this.baseUrl}app/shops/`
  headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  });



  constructor(
    private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private cookieService: CookieService,
  ) { }

  /* Product CRUD */

  /* ADD: add a product to the server */
  addProduct(): Observable<Product> {

    const productUrl = `${this.baseProductUrl}`
    return this.httpClient.post<Product>(productUrl, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()})

  }

  // DELETE: delete the product from the server 
  deleteProduct(product_code: number): Observable<Product> {

    const productUrl = `${this.baseProductUrl}${product_code}/`
    return this.httpClient.delete<Product>(productUrl, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()})

  }

  // PUT: update the product on the server 
  updateProduct(product_code: Product): Observable<any> {

    const productUrl = `${this.baseProductUrl}${product_code}/`
    return this.httpClient.put(productUrl, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()})

  }

  // GET: get all products from the server 
  getProducts() {

    return this.httpClient.get<Product[]>(this.baseProductUrl, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()});
    
  }

  // GET: get one product from the server 
  getProduct(product_code: number): Observable<Product> {
    const productUrl = `${this.baseProductUrl}${product_code}/`
    return this.httpClient.get<Product>(productUrl, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()});
    
  }

  // GET: get all categories from the server 
  getCategories() {

    return this.httpClient.get<Category[]>(this.baseCategoryUrl, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()});
    
  }

  // GET: get one category from the server 
  getCategory(id: number): Observable<Category> {
    const url = `${this.baseCategoryUrl}${id}/`;

    return this.httpClient.get<Category>(url, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()});
    
  }

  // GET: get all shops from the server 
  getShops() {

    return this.httpClient.get<Shop[]>(this.baseShopUrl, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()});
    
  }

  // GET: get one shop from the server 
  getShop(business_reg: string): Observable<Shop> {
    const url = `${this.baseShopUrl}${business_reg}/`;

    return this.httpClient.get<Shop>(url, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()});
    
  }

  
  

  

  loginUser(authData: any) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(authData);
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}auth/`, body, {headers: this.headers});
  }

  registerUser(authData: any) {
    const body = JSON.stringify(authData);
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseUrl}user/users/`, body, {headers: this.headers});
  }

  getAuthHeaders() {
    const token = this.cookieService.get('ur-token')
    return new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`
    });
  }

}
```

***dashboard.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/Product';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from '../../api.service';
import { Category } from '../../models/Category';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[] =[]




  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private router: Router,
    private apiService: ApiService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProducts()
  }

  getProducts(): void {
    const urToken = this.cookieService.get('ur-token')
    if (!urToken) {
      this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
    } else {
      this.apiService.getProducts().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.products = data;
        console.log('selectedProduct', this.products);
      },
      error => console.log(error)
    );
    }
  }

  

  delete(product: Product): void {
    this.products = this.products.filter(h => h !== product);
    this.apiService.deleteProduct(product.product_code).subscribe();
  }
}
```

***dashboard.component.html***

```
<section>

<div class="container">
    <h1>My Dashboard <button class="btn" routerLink="add/">Add Product</button></h1>
    <div class="card-wrapper">
        <div class="card" *ngFor="let product of products">
            <!-- card left -->
            <div class="product-content">
                <img class="img-fluid image" src="{{product.product_image}}">
                <div class="product-item">
                    <h2 class="product-title">{{ product.name }}</h2>
                    <a class="edit"><button class="btn" routerLink="edit/{{ product.product_code }}">Edit</button></a>
                    <a class="delete"><button class="btn" (click)="delete(product)">Delete</button></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

***product-form.component.ts***

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/models/Product';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-form',
  templateUrl: './product-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-form.component.css']
})
export class ProductFormComponent implements OnInit {

  product!: Product;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private apiService: ApiService,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProduct()
  }

  getProduct(): void {
    const product_code = Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('product_code'));
    this.apiService.getProduct(product_code)
      .subscribe(product => this.product = product);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  save(): void {
    this.apiService.updateProduct(this.product)
      .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
  }

}
```

***product-form.component.html***

```
<div *ngIf="product">
    <input id="product-code" [(ngModel)]="product.product_code" placeholder="product_code">
    <input id="product-name" [(ngModel)]="product.name" placeholder="name">
    <input id="product-price" [(ngModel)]="product.price" placeholder="price">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your API service the HTTP POST and PUT calls are missing payload data.

Can you try passing the data for your product as a parameter?

The product code for the PUT should be in a class with populated data (from your component) so that your backend API can pick up the code (and other product data fields) and update your data. Your backend API methods should then read the request data from the body (the payload).

For your Angular API service methods you should pass product data parameters from your component as follows:

/* ADD: add a product to the server */
addProduct(product: Product): Observable {
const productUrl = `${this.baseProductUrl}`
return this.httpClient.post(productUrl, product, {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()})
}

// PUT: update the product on the server
updateProduct(product: Product): Observable {
const productUrl = `${this.baseProductUrl}${product_code}/`
return this.httpClient.put(productUrl, product {headers: this.getAuthHeaders()})
}

There is a post (https://andrewhalil.com/2020/12/01/calling-web-apis-from-your-angular-ui/) on my site that shows how this is done in Angular.

Comment: This helped solve my question thanks you! It is much appreciated Andrew!